# flutter: issue with packages version in dependencies

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

```
  http: ^0.13.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.6
  flutter_launcher_icons:
  hexcolor: ^1.0.6
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.11.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.2
  intl: ^0.17.0
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.6
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.0
  provider: ^4.3.2+1
  firebase_core: ^1.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.0
```

Comment: Please add the problem and the error message so that someone can help you.

Comment: Add the message flutter gives you so that we can configure the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dependency problem after updating to a new version of flutter, try to update libraries version also which crash your apps due to the dependency version problem.
If the problem is in the library just clone the library from Github and correct dependencies there and use it in pubsec.yaml